# Video calling not recieving from android to iphone vice versa using QuickBlox

Tags: android, quickblox

## Hello coders

i am making an app with video calling functionality and i have used QuickBlox SDK webrtc for Android and IOS.

it works perfectly to android to android and IOS to IOS,

But my problem is that i am not able receive or call video call from IOS app to Android app and vice versa.

Is there any fixes ???

Comment: Hi kishan,i am working on the same type application where i have to set the communication between Web(asp.net) and mobile viceversa. Can you provide some guidlines to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in new version of [SDK v 1.0.5](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios)

Comment: hey dude i am working with Quickblox Android SDK, version 2.2.4 isn't it updated SDK?

Comment: 2.2.4 is the latest version, we tested 2.2.4 android and 1.0.5 iOS and there is no such problems